# Increase icon scaling on xfce4 desktop

Tags: xfce, display

I have this virtual machine using the xfce4 desktop for my schooling. I have a 3840 x 2160 display which the virtual machine decides that it will make everything tiny when I use this display. I use virtualbox but using the scaling settings on that compromises my resolution quite a lot. I found one window scaling which I set from 1x to 2x which slightly helped but it isn't enough. Is there a way to further increase this scale up using the command line as this is the largest size but everything still looks tiny. [image: my appearance settings]

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be made larger by using a fractional custom setting for Scale in the Display settings. A fractional setting is needed because a setting greater than 1x counterintuitively *decreases* the size of everything. See the article "XFCE Hi DPI screens" at https://discovery.endeavouros.com/desktop-environments/xfce-hi-dpi-screens/2021/06/ for more info.